# Getting User-Defined Packages to Work in Windows Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, package

I've read the reference page on packages but I don't seem to be able to import modules from within my library's folders. Here's my library:

```
K:\web\cgi\lib>dir
 Volume in drive K is Krusty
 Volume Serial Number is E889-7AE2

 Directory of K:\web\cgi\lib

16/12/2012  07:52    <DIR>          .
16/12/2012  07:52    <DIR>          ..
16/12/2012  07:52    <DIR>          database
16/12/2012  07:21    <DIR>          kmz_builder
16/12/2012  05:45                21 site_consts.py
16/12/2012  07:42                 0 __init__.py
           2 File(s)             21 bytes
           4 Dir(s)  267,263,594,496 bytes free
```

And here's the database folder:

```
 K:\web\cgi\lib>dir database
 Volume in drive K is Krusty
 Volume Serial Number is E889-7AE2

 Directory of K:\web\cgi\lib\database

16/12/2012  07:52    <DIR>          .
16/12/2012  07:52    <DIR>          ..
13/12/2012  01:52             3,643 dbops.py
12/12/2012  12:49            11,414 dbspec.py
08/12/2012  11:30             4,104 MyDB.py
               3 File(s)         19,161 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  267,263,594,496 bytes free
```

Environment variable is set:

```
K:\web\cgi\lib>echo %PYTHONPATH%
k:\web\cgi\lib
```

I seem to be able to import from the top level of the library (site_consts.py) but not a subfolder:

```
K:\web\cgi\lib>python
ActivePython 2.7.1.4 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Feb  7 2011, 11:33:02) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import site_consts
>>> import database.dbspec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named database.dbspec
>>>
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: Unless it's a typo the `k` in your echo for the `%PYTHONPATH%` seems to be lowercase and your actual path seems to be uppercase. Also, I don't see a `__init__.py` file in your `database` directory.

Comment: This is on Windows - shouldn't matter, surely?

Comment: Probably not... to be honest I haven't used Windows in several years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a blank file called `__init__.py` in the `database` directory. The `__init__.py` file tells Python that the directory should be treated as a [package](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).